# При запуске открывается меню, нажимаю на "Game", а вместо игры серый экран, хотя такого быть не должно. Что делать?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import sys
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
pg.font.init()

def Collision(bx, by, ball, rect):
    if bx > 0:
        dx = ball.right - rect.left
    else:
        dx = rect.right - ball.left
    if by > 0:
        dy = ball.bottom - rect.top
    else:
        dy = rect.bottom - ball.top

    if (dx - dy) < 5:
        bx, by == -bx, by
    if dx > dy:
        by *= -1
    if dy > dx:
        bx *= -1

    return bx, by

width = 800
height = 670
scr = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))
screen = pg.Surface((800, 640))
info = pg.Surface((800, 30))
clock = pg.time.Clock()

class Menu:

        def __init__(self, punkts =[400, 350, u'Punkt',(70, 130, 180), (255, 255, 0)]):
            self.punkts = punkts

        def render(self, surface, font, num_punkt):
            for i in self.punkts:
                if num_punkt == i[5]:
                    surface.blit(font.render(i[2], 1, i[4]), (i[0], i[1]))
                else:
                    surface.blit(font.render(i[2], 1, i[3]), (i[0], i[1]))

        def menu(self):
            done = True
            font_menu = pg.font.SysFont('Arial', 50)
            punkt = 0
            while done:
                scr.fill((0, 0, 0))

                mp = pg.mouse.get_pos()
                for i in self.punkts:
                    if i[0] < mp[0] < i[0] + 155 and i[1] < mp[1] < i[1] + 50:
                        punkt = i[5]
                    self.render(screen, font_menu, punkt)

                for e in pg.event.get():
                    if e.type == pg.QUIT:
                            sys.exit()
                            
                    if e.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                        if e.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                            exit()
                        if e.key == pg.K_UP:
                            if punkt > 0:
                                punkt -= 1
                        if e.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                            if punkt < len(self.punkts) - 1:
                                punkt += 1
                    if e.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and e.button == 1:
                        if punkt == 0:
                            done = False
                        elif punkt == 1:
                            exit()

                scr.blit(screen, (0, 0))
                pg.display.flip()

text = pg.font.SysFont('Century Gothic', 40, bold = False)

blk = [pg.Rect(50 * i, 50 + 50 * j, 50, 50) for i in range(16) for j in
       range(3)] 
cl_blk = [pg.Color("orange") for i in range(16) for j in range(3)]
player = pg.Rect(-12, 460, 100 * 1.2, 16)
score, kolblock = 0, len(blk)

R = 12
ball = pg.Rect(23, 430, R, R + 12)
bx, by, life = 1, -1, 3

found, play, gameover, win  = True, False, False, False

punkts = [(120, 140, u'Game', (255, 255, 0), (70, 130, 180), 0),
          (130, 210, u'Quit', (255, 255, 0), (70, 130, 180), 1)]
game = Menu(punkts)
game.menu()

done = True
pg.key.set_repeat(1, 1)
arrow_color = 100
while done:
    scr.fill(pg.Color('black'))

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            exit()
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            found, play = False, True

    key = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pg.K_RIGHT] and player.right < width:
        player.x += 10
        if found == True:
            ball.x += 10

    if key[pg.K_LEFT] and player.left > 0:
        player.x -= 10
        if found == True:
            ball.x -= 10

    if play == True:
        ball.x += 4 * bx
        ball.y += 4 * by

        if ball.x < R or ball.x >= width - R:
            bx *= -1
        if ball.y - 50 < R:
            by *= -1

        if ball.colliderect(player) and by > 0:
            bx, by = Collision(bx, by, ball, player)

        destroy = ball.collidelist(blk)
        if destroy != -1:
            destrect = blk.pop(destroy)
            bx, by = Collision(bx, by, ball, destrect)
            score += 1

        if score == kolblock:
            play, win = False, True

    screen.fill((50, 50, 50))
    info.fill((45, 80, 45))
    arrow_color += 0.1
    if arrow_color > 99:
        arrow_color = 20

    pg.draw.aaline(scr, pg.Color('orange'), [0, 60], [width, 60])
    [pg.draw.rect(scr, cl_blk[color], i) for color, i in enumerate(blk)]
    pg.draw.rect(scr, pg.Color('blue'), player)
    pg.draw.circle(scr, pg.Color('white'), ball.center, R)

    Tlife = text.render(f'Life: {life}', 1, pg.Color('black'))
    scr.blit(Tlife, (15, 5))
    Tscore = text.render(f'Score: {score}/{kolblock}', 1, pg.Color('black'))
    scr.blit(Tscore, (160, 5))
    if gameover == True:
        Tgameover = text.render('Game over!', 1, pg.Color('RED'))
        scr.blit(Tgameover, (10, 200))
    elif win:
        Twin = text.render('You win!', 1, pg.Color('Blue'))
        scr.blit(Twin, (10, 200))

    scr.blit(info, (0, 0))
    scr.blit(screen, (0, 30))
    pg.display.flip()
    pg.time.delay(5)
pg.quit()
```

Comment: вы вначале рисуете все элементы игры `pg.draw.aaline`, `rect`, `circle`, а затем рисуете фон `scr.blit(screen, (0, 0))` и закрашиваете все что нарисовали до этого

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, вы запускаете код игры после кода меню, из-за чего игра запускается сразу после закрытия меню. Вместо этого вы должны запускать код игры только в том случае, если пользователь выбирает в меню пункт «Игра».

Вы можете сделать это, добавив условие для проверки значения переменной punkt в методе Menu.menu(). Если переменная punkt равна индексу опции «Game» в списке точек, вы можете запустить код игры.

Вот пример того, как вы можете этого добиться:

```
def menu(self):
    done = True
    font_menu = pg.font.SysFont('Arial', 50)
    punkt = 0
    pg.init()
    while done:
        scr.fill((0, 0, 0))

        mp = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        for i in self.punkts:
            if i[0] < mp[0] < i[0] + 155 and i[1] < mp[1] < i[1] + 50:
                punkt = i[5]
            self.render(screen, font_menu, punkt)

        for e in pg.event.get():
            if e.type == pg.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

            if e.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    exit()
                if e.key == pg.K_UP:
                    if punkt > 0:
                        punkt -= 1
                if e.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                    if punkt < len(self.punkts) - 1:
                        punkt += 1
            if e.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and e.button == 1:
                if punkt == 0:
                    done = False
                elif punkt == 1:
                    exit()

        scr.blit(screen, (0, 0))
        pg.display.flip()
```

Comment: Но разве проверка не была проведена здесь?: if e.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and e.button == 1:
                if punkt == 0:
                    done = False
                elif punkt == 1:
                    exit()